# proof that the double cone is not a topological manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I think I have to consider an open neighborhood $U$ of the vertex $p$ and an homeomorphism to an open ball in $\mathbb R^2$ then since $U - \{p\}$ is not connected and the ball minus one point (the image of the vertex $p$ ) is still connected, we cannot have such homeomorphism.

But I wonder if it is right to consider such an open neighborhood of the vertex since it will go out of the cone near the vertex, and thus will not be contained in the double cone in the first place.

Comment: or maybe Im just confusing things and someone could help me with a proper proof

Comment: The intersection between a small open ball centered at $p$ and the double cone is a neighbourhood of $p$ in the double cone. Nothing "goes out".

Comment: You are right I did not consider the intersection with the double cone. Thank you.